# Show all files recently committed by me on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-diff

Is it possible to show all files committed by me recently (or since a specific commit) in the Changes tool window?

The idea is that I can keep making small commits on my feature branch and when I finish my task I can review everything I did, run an analysis tool, etc, before pushing or merging with the master branch.

Comment: Why not use Log tab of the Changes window?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: That was easy :) added as answer, pls consider accepting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[Log tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/log-tab.html)** of the `Changes Tool` window. It is available for Git and shows committed changes in all branches of local+remote repositories; including author information.